# Nginx rewrite rule for static content in Drupal

Tags: drupal, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite static file requests from /imgs/blue.gif to /files/images/spacer.gif but can't seem to get it working.

I have tried putting the follow line into the / location before the "try_files $uri @rewrite":

```
rewrite ^/imgs/blue.gif  /files/images/spacer.gif permanent;
```

I also tried adding it to the @rewrite location before the "rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;" line, but that didn't work either.

Hope somebody might be able to help me on this.

P.S.: I am using Drupal and have setup my config file similar to this one: http://wiki.nginx.org/Drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your website configuration.

[Here is an example of working Nginx configuration](http://phoenixdesign.fr/tutoriels/linux/migration-drupal-apache-nginx)
>
I put my redirection juste after the root declaration like this:

```
rewrite ^/address_to_intercept http://mysite.com/address_to_go permanent;
```

If it doesn't work, check your error log and post your configuration.